# How can I avoid calling same function inside an inner pythonical style loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, loops

I have a high cpu consuming function, lets say:

```
def high_cost_function(p):
  ... lots of operations...
  return p
```

which I want to use under an inner loop in python:

Example:

```
paths1= ['a','b','c']
paths2= ['b','c','d']
[any(x.startswith(high_cost_function(y)) for x in paths1) for y in paths2]
```

Which returns properly: `[True, True, False]`

However, as you can see, I am forced to call `high_cost_function(y)` for each of the x in paths1.

If it was a normal loop, I would probably simply do:

```
for y in paths2:
  tmp_var = high_cost_function(y)
  for x in paths1:
    ...
    use tmp_var
    ...
```

Is there anyway to implement this in the first "pythonical stylish way"??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterate over a (generated) list of `y`s to which `high_cost_function` has already been applied:

```
[any(x.startswith(y) for x in paths1) for y in map(high_cost_function, paths2)]
```

Comment: Pedantically, `map(high_cost_function, paths2)` is not a list in Python 3: it's an iterator.

Comment: Hence the *"(generated)"* in front of it, since that makes the sentence more understandable than "iterate over an iterator", which—while correct—sounds confusing.

Answer (score 3):

The [answer by deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69807573/1639625) is already perfect for the given use case. In a more general case, when you might also need `y` itself, you could use a nested generator expression (creating a `dict` here to illustrate using both):

```
{y: any(x.startswith(hcf_y) for x in paths1)
 for (y, hcf_y) in ((y, high_cost_function(y)) for y in paths2)}
```

Or use a second loop iterating over a single-element list to sort-of define a variable inside the list-comp:

```
{y: any(x.startswith(hcf_y) for x in paths1)
 for y in paths2 for hcf_y in [high_cost_function(y)]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If results of `high_cost_function` are not large, you could also use [caching](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)

```
from functools import lru_cache
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def high_cost_function(p):
  ... lots of operations...
  return p
```